# Jasmine test complaining about 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have checked other questions similar to my problem. but this problem can apparently be different in every case. 
Angular Jasmine Test complains 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'fields.forEach')at discoverDependentFields

Here is my discoverDependentFields function

```
discoverDependentFields($scope.response.Fields);

function discoverDependentFields(fields) {
    fields.forEach(function (field) {
        field.DependencyFieldEvaluated = '';
        if (field.DependencyField) {
            var foundFields = fields.filter(function (fieldToFind) { return fieldToFind.Name === field.DependencyField; });
            if (foundFields.length === 1) {
                field.DependencyFieldEvaluated = foundFields[0];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and in the test I have this bit

```
        this.controller('MyController', {
            '$scope': this.scope,                              
            }
        });

 this.scope.response.Fields = [
                {
                    Name: "UserIdentity",
                    Value: {
                        "FirstName": "John"
                    },
                    PropertyName: "User.Identity"
                }
            ];
```

I use the value of field.DependencyFieldEvaluated in a function in a directive like this

```
function dependencyMet(field) {
                    var dependentField = field.DependencyFieldEvaluated;

                    var met = compareToDependencyValue(field, dependentField.Value);
                    return met;
                }
```

I have no idea why it is complaining

Comment: Just guessing here but considering it looks like `discoverDependentFields` is executed right away, shouldn't you set up the `scope.response.Fields` *before* running `this.controller('MyController'...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
discoverDependentFields($scope.response.Fields);
```

is a line in your controller, then you need to setup the `$scope.response.Fields` data **before** instantiating the controller. In other words, swap the order of operations in your test to be

```
this.scope = {};
// or maybe this.scope = $rootScope.$new()

this.scope.response = {
    Fields: [{
        Name: "UserIdentity",
        Value: {
            FirstName: "John"
        },
        PropertyName: "User.Identity"
    }]
};

this.controller('MyController', {
    $scope: this.scope,
});
```

Comment: By swaping that I get this new error now. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.scope.response')

Comment: I assumed you already had a `response` object property on your scope. Check my edit above

Comment: Thanks Phil, this.scope is not defined. I am wondering why it used to work before I added that discoverDependentFields bit to the controller. for example I had $scope.completeApplicationFields = $filter("isNamedField")(false, nonPrimaryFields, $scope.response.Fields); and the tests where fine the way it was

Comment: Normally you would initialise your test scope via `var scope = $rootScope.$new()` (after injecting `$rootScope`) or just a plain object of you don't need any scope life-cycle hooks / events, however you didn't show enough of your test code so I was left guessing

Comment: your explanation and code is generally right. My case was a bit more complicated though. Any way took your advice and got it work finally.